# I have issue while automating Odoo application

Tags: java, selenium

i am automating Odoo pos application. but while adding product to the cart, i got error like "Element is not clickable at point (659,166)". i have already created 1 item and trying to add that in cart but element is not found. need help.

```
      package odoo1;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class odoo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); 



        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);



        // for Log in functionality
        driver.get("https://www.odoo.com/trial?selected_app=point_of_sale");
        driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("mark");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("mark@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("company-name")).sendKeys("odooo");
        driver.findElement(By.id("phone")).sendKeys("561234897");
        driver.findElement(By.id("country-id")).sendKeys("India");
        driver.findElement(By.name("lang")).sendKeys("English");
        Select sell=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("company_size")));
        sell.selectByIndex(2);;
        Select sell1=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("plan")));
        sell1.selectByIndex(2);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapwrap']/main/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/input[8]")).click();

        // for creating product

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/a[2]/div[2]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/ul[1]/li[2]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/ul[1]/li[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/button")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_4']")).sendKeys("iphone");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_4']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_13']")).sendKeys("abcd");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_14']")).sendKeys("123456");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_15']"));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_16']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_16']")).sendKeys("25000");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_20']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='o_field_input_20']")).sendKeys("25000");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button[1]")).click();



    Thread.sleep(900);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/nav/div/ul[1]/li[1]/a/span")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div/span[2]/div[1]")).click();


    Thread.sleep(700);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button")).click();

    Thread.sleep(5000);



    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/div/div/div/span[2]/div[1]/img")).click();

   }


    }
```

Comment: You should share your code along with error stacktrace

Comment: Share your code and html of that element.It is better if you share what you have tried.

Comment: I have checked on of the site of Odoo [https://store.webkul.com](https://store.webkul.com/) , in which the cart is not click-able, whereas when you hover the mouse its listing the things added to cart.I think you need to use action [http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-perform-mouseover-action-in-selenium-webdriver). Please refer this link for more details

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the exception, it looks like the right path is not selected.
I have just checked the website which you are trying to automate.

**Steps I have followed:**

1. Click on Open Cart tab.
2. Select Shipping option.
3. Click on **Add to Cart** for the product which you want to add in your path.

**Xpath Used for Add To Cart button:**

//h3[normalize-space()="Opencart Marketplace"]/../div[3]//button

I have selected the product "Opencart Marketplace". You can select any product you want. Just replace **Opencart Marketplace** with the product which you want to select.

**Code:**

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "src/geckodriver");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("https://store.webkul.com/OpenCart-Modules.html");

Thread.sleep(2);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h3[normalize-space()='Opencart Marketplace']/../div[3]//button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='product_cart_container']/button")).click();